# Delaying display of page until [ngClass] has been evaluated

Tags: angular5, angular-routing, angular-ng-class

**Background** I have a header component having [ngClass] attached to top div.

**Question** Is it possible to delay displaying of page until [ngClass] has been evaluated? We used to have ng-cloak in AngularJs. Do we have something similar in Angular?

**Why I need it** This would help me in avoiding the undesirable flicker effect.

**Header template**

```html
<div [ngClass]="{'no-hero': headerType === 400, 'restaurant-page': headerType === 200, 'restaurant-list': headerType === 300}"
    class="top-section">
  <div class="top-section-bg">
  </div>
 // Code removed for brevity
</div>
```